# Delivery delay in days - discrete or continuous?

Tags: r, distributions

I am working on a task and I am unsure if my data is continuous or discrete.

I have data about the delivery time from a production to an assembly factory. The time is measured in days, for example 2,5,7,14 days.

I have to find a distribution matching this data. But I am unsure if this data is continuous or discrete?

Comment: Can it be just 2,5,7,14 days or can it be any integer (or real if you proxy hours as fraction of days)?  Anyway often when you have empirical distributions that are “sparse” enough you want to proxy them with continuous ones, via kernels or parametric distributions.. but it depends on your data and what you want to do with such data.. what’s your task exactly?

Comment: Why do you "have to find a distribution..." for these data? What difference does it make if they're discrete or continuous? What will depend on which answer you go with? (I'm not necessarily criticizing, this is certainly fine as an 'academic' question.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using an arbitrary precision data type (if you're not sure, then very likely not) your observations will always be rounded to some finite precision on your computer, so in that sense appear 'discretized'. I would generally model arrival times as a continuous variable, unless for some reason it doesn't make sense to think of something taking 5.5  in your specific application.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at previous answer - time is continuous. On the other hand dates are discrete. Delivery companies often work on daily bases, delivering for example every day at 9-10AM. As most discrete distributions have their continuous equivalents, you can choose what is more appropriate here. You can also make use from both of these options.

Personally I would use rule of thumb whether to treat this data as count data or as continuous time variable: If it is more concentrated around few values, like the number of children in families, I would try to think about kind of discrete distribution like Poisson, possibly using Poisson regression in analysis. If it has more values and is closer to distribution of age in years in general population, then i would think of it more as continuous data.

There is also a good hint in scientific literature, but takes some more time - make a literature review, find some good papers analysing similar problems and similar data. How scientists treat such variable within this particular field? This would be the strongest suggestion.